# Google Direction API cannot find my API Key

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an android app where a customer requests a worker for pickuplocation, so i am using google direction library to show routes between the customer and worker but direction API keeps throwing error saying that you must use an API key to make requests to google cloud platform, already i have created a project in google cloud console and generated my key.
Here is what i have done;
First of all i started my project without a billing account, then in the process of my project i was required to create a billing account in order to make direction request so i linked my project what
What i did;
i added my API key to manifest
i have already enabled places API and direction API
in the direction part i am using google direction library, this one
i added it to app build-gradle

compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'

and here is a sample of code in my activity for direction request since i am using the above library i dont know whether it is because i created the project then billing account, what might be the problem? 
Even places API does not function properly

```
private void getRouteToMarker(LatLng customerpickuplocation) {
Routing routing = new Routing.Builder()
            .travelMode(AbstractRouting.TravelMode.DRIVING)
            .withListener(this)
            .alternativeRoutes(false)
            .waypoints(new LatLng(lat, lng), customerpickuplocation)
            .build();
    routing.execute();
}
@Override
public void onRoutingFailure(RouteException e) {
    if (e != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong, Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
@Override
public void onRoutingSuccess(ArrayList<Route> route, int shortestRouteIndex) {
    if (polylines.size() > 0) {
        for (Polyline poly : polylines) {
            poly.remove();
        }
    }

    polylines = new ArrayList<>();
    //add route(s) to the map.
    for (int i = 0; i < route.size(); i++) {

        //In case of more than 5 alternative routes
        int colorIndex = i % COLORS.length;

        PolylineOptions polyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polyOptions.color(getResources().getColor(COLORS[colorIndex]));
        polyOptions.width(10 + i * 3);
        polyOptions.addAll(route.get(i).getPoints());
        Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polyOptions);
        polylines.add(polyline);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Route " + (i + 1) + ": distance - " + route.get(i).getDistanceValue() + ": duration - " + route.get(i).getDurationValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have come up with a solution but not a good security measure, by adding key to getRouteToMarker() method

```
private void getRouteToMarker(LatLng customerpickuplocation) {
    Routing routing = new Routing.Builder()
                .travelMode(AbstractRouting.TravelMode.DRIVING)
                .withListener(this)
                .alternativeRoutes(false)
                .waypoints(new LatLng(lat, lng), customerpickuplocation) 
                .key("your api key")
                .build();
        routing.execute();

}
```